# Java auto web form filling

Tags: java, forms, jsp, web

In my web application currently i need to hard code the values to submit the form but now my requirement is to make it auto form filling to display the values on the respective text boxes. Please someone tell me how do we go about this?

Comment: <input type="text" value="whatever you want" /> ???

Comment: maybe have a look on <select></select> html component? and fill the options? seems to be a better solutions

Answer (score 1):

if your intention is to show text boxes with values already present, you could do this

```
<input type = "text" name = "myText" value = "xxxx" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Before submit form, you can call this function

```
function autoFill() {
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var obj in elems) {
            if (elems[obj].type == 'text') {
                elems[obj].value = "Any Value";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: some pages don't fill the place with the value!!

Answer (score 1):

Create method in your page Servlet, which would return value of you input.

**Something like:**

```
 public String getParam() {
       return (request.getParameter('inpName') != null)?request.getParameter('inpName'):"";
    }
```

and your input in jsp

```
<input name="inpName" value="${manager.param}">
```

So the value that have been before in input would reload and be filled in your input. Or you could place any value in method for fullfilling.

Answer (score 0):

If you use just from the value then you can write some js code

```
document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].value = 'ME'
document.querySelectorAll("input")[2].value = '10'
```

copy your codes and run them in: inspect >  **console**